# Being an offline iOS developer

Tags: ios, isolation

I am currently studying for the sake of a big company I'm working for the creation of an iOS dev team.

Long story short, we handle very sensitive informations and code, so we vould like to avoid at all cost to connect this platform to the internet.

So my question is: is it feasible to develop a iOS app while being on an isolated network? I'm thinking about dev licence, certificates, IDs, profiles and so on, knowing that once developed, we already have a deployment structure.

Being my self a junior iOS dev, I have a few doubts, so any enlightment is welcome ;)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably too broad to work well on Stack Overflow... it *probably* won't work on http://programmers.stackexchange.com either, but it might be worth chekcing out their faq and Meta site. I don't know, it's been a while since I've been there. If you ask this someplace else, you should make clearer what this will entail: will the entire app have to run outside the app store? Because that's a whole different level of "being offline" than just developing it without any Internet connection (which should be feasible or almost feasible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a distribution structure already your question might be "How do I sign and distribute apps outside of the Apple Store?" If that's the case take a look at the Apple Enterprise program which allows signing and distributing your own apps. The second question on how to avoid access of the device to the internet (no network connectivity) would be to implement Mobile Device Management solution. This allows you to configure and manage the device and might give you what you want. Google for "mdm ios provider".